# How do configure optional or "extraneous" URLs?

Tags: url, configuration, url-rewriting

How would you configure/handle extraneous/optional URLs entities (aliases, maybe)?

SO is a good example:

- stackoverflow.com/questions/99999999/
- stackoverflow.com/questions/99999999/**question-goes-here** (bad example, but I couldn't think of better)

Amazon URLs are even more confusing (e.g., the [Kindle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FI73MA))

- amazon.com/gp/product/B000FI73MA/
- amazon.com/**Kindle-Amazons-Wireless-Reading-Device**/dp/B000FI73MA/

[**EDIT**] This probably isn't the best plan-of-action, but I'm really asking this in general vs. for any single server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technique is commonly known as url rewriting. If you are looking out for a solution in IIS, you can use **[ISAPI rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)**, which is quite similar to [**mod_rewrite**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for apache. Or else, you can go for **[ASP.Net MVC routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)** mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Apache, take a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (if manually configuring URLs):

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&view=$2&args=$3
```

Otherwise I let the MVC framework handle it and taylor the controller's arguments as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite is often used, at least under Linux with Apache.

Answer (score -1):

That's a task for your web app, not your web server.

On URL=>file mappings, like PHP (or static webservers) it's tricky; but on MVC frameworks it's quite natural, even on PHP MVC frameworks.