# Why isn't this mod_rewrite rule working as documented?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to debug URL rewriting on a hosted site, where I don't have access to `vhost.conf` and so can't set up a rewrite log.  How else can I debug rules that aren't working?

This is the rule I'm trying to straighten out, if anyone has any insight:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.([^/]+)$ xslt.php [L]
```

What I expect to have happen: URLs that have dots but no slashes to be rewritten to point to `xslt.php` and then stop rewriting, so that it doesn't go into a loop.  What actually happens?  500 Internal Server Error (which smells like it *is* looping).  I know I can add a `RewriteCond` to specifically exclude `xslt.php`, but I'd prefer to understand why this is breaking first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't it loop?  xslt.php has dots but no slashes.  Try changing your options to [L,NS].

Edit: Ah, I see.  What you're missing is that [L] terminates all rewriting for this request, but a subrequest is still generated that gets its own rewrite pass.  [NS] suppresses that pass.

Comment: Probably is.  It's deep enough magic that there's a lot of territory left past "pretty good". :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`L` flag causes a restart of the rewrite process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499970/why-would-modrewrite-rewrite-twice/500716#500716) using the new, rewritten URL `xslt.php` that then is also matched by your pattern.

So try this:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^xslt\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.([^/]+)$ xslt.php [L]
```